# PHP sockets stdin appending to data received

Tags: php, sockets, select, stdin

I am using sockets in PHP to create a simple command line based chat.  It works ok, but there is one main issue that is making it almost unusable.  When there are multiple people in the chat and one person is typing a message and the other sends a message the person typing the message gets the message received appended to what they are typing.  Is there anyway around this?  I'm using stdin and stream select.  Here is a piece from the client:

```
$uin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while (true) {
  $r = array($socket, $uin);
  $w = NULL;
  $e = NULL;

  if (0 < stream_select($r, $w, $e, 0)) {
    foreach ($r as $i => $fd) {
      if ($fd == $uin) {
        $text = (fgets($uin));
        fwrite($socket, $text);
      } else {
        $text = fgets($socket);
        print $text;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Use a screen management library to display output in a different part of the screen from reading input.

Answer (score 0):

The code outputs a message to stdout everytime a full string is waiting in $socket.

The only way to get around that is to put the text to a variable ($outtext) in stead of printing it. Then you can display it whenever you are ready to read it, such as before writing to the outgoing socket...

```
$uin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while (true) {
  $r = array($socket, $uin);
  $w = NULL;
  $e = NULL;
  $outtext = '';

  if (0 < stream_select($r, $w, $e, 0)) {
    foreach ($r as $i => $fd) {
      if ($fd == $uin) {
        $text = (fgets($uin));
        print $outtext;
        $outtext = '';
        fwrite($socket, $text);
      } else {
        $text = fgets($socket);
        $outtext .= $text;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The downside being that it will only display incoming text when you press enter. The only way around that would be to use something other than fgets().

I'm assuming this is just an experiment - event driven programming with Node.js or similar would be much better for this type of thing.